# How to let tomcat main thread get more clients' request instead of sleeping for future.isDone()

Tags: java, tomcat, future, completable-future, callable

I read about `Callable` and `Futures` in java.

I want to run a java web-server that does some background callable.

I have a few questions:

1) `future.get()` blocks my main thread.

```
while (!future.isDone()) { 
Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

is a busy wait.

How should I release the main thread (tomcat thread) to dispatch more clients' requests?

If it sleeps in a `while` it somehow context switched to get more clients' requests?

2) In general, how does tomcat makes the server stateless?

meaning each field of my Java server class is thread safe because a new instance is created for each client request?

Comment: For freeing up the main thread, you can use DeferredResult

Comment: do i need to? i understand tomcat gives a new thread to each httpRequest? so maybe future.get() is ok for that case? why do we need future.isDone() if the thread 
is dedicated to each request anyhow?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to accomplish? Are you trying to use Tomcat as your application server, and you want your application to do some background web-service calling? Or are you trying to implement an application server (or something like that) and want to know how Tomcat works so you can copy ideas from there?

Comment: It sounds like what you really want here (assuming you are just writing your own servlets that contact other web services) is to use the "asynchronous" servlet model where your code can do whatever it wants in its own thread and periodically ask Tomcat to move the bytes back and forth between your code and the client, but not hold-up the request-processing threads on potentially long-running work. To do that, you need to read all about "asynchronous processing" for servlets. It requires that you re-think how your application interacts with the client.